# Issue when creating/building a new project in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just as a disclaimer, I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question, and even posted to the Unity forums for an answer. No one has responded and it's been a few weeks now. Anyway, to the problem:
I'm not sure what happened, I've even reinstalled multiple times to stop this error from happening. I'm new to this so please be gentle if there is an easy fix. Basically, when I create a new project and try to open it I get an error. I'm not sure if this will have any repercussions when building an actual game/app. If not then I'm okay with having it there, but I do want to know why it's happening in the first place. I've tried running with Administrative privileges as well, but it wasn't successful. Any help or input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! I will go ahead and post the picture of the error.
[Unity Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLo0U.jpg)

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Get out of the habit of elevating to admin to try and solve problems you do not understand. Visual Studio can execute scripts found in packages it downloads. You never want to run those as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the folder of the assets (Use Windows Key + r Then Type "%apppdata%) and delete the folders that the error gives you. I've had this issue before, that seemed to fix it up for me.

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of the errors for me. I appreciate your help.